# Touchscreen + screen keyboard + Sound + mic + speaker + screen Pen + headphone + external mic + touchpad right,left click, just nothing is working

Tags: sound, microphone, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard, hp-touchpad

I try everything, starting from down grating the kernel to installing ubuntu back to 20.04 to 22.04, 23.10, anything I can find over the net all the ideas people shared tried. for sound, mix, touch screen, if something is working then some other sh*** stop working, but for now I just able to fix external mic and headphone, but it is working temporary after just one restart everything again stop working.

In Ubuntu 20.04 computer builtin sound, mic, speaker had problem but external mic, headphone, and touch screen were ok, but after update to 22.04 everything stopped working

If there is a full driver package or a full package that solve all these problems exist please let me know. else I am really feed-up and tired with ubuntu and its issues for the last 5 years.

## My computer details is

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-39-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.9
    tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 42.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Convertible System: HP
    product: HP Spectre Folio Convertible 13-ak0xxx v: Type1ProductConfigId
    serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 31
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8503 v: 14.42 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI-[Legacy]: Insyde v: F.15 date: 03/26/2019
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 36.5 Wh (95.8%) condition: 38.1/54.3 Wh (70.1%)
    volts: 8.8 min: 7.7 model: COMPAL PABAS0241231 type: Li-ion
    serial: <filter> status: Charging
  Device-1: hid-0018:04F3:284A.0001-battery model: ELAN2514:00 04F3:284A
    serial: N/A charge: N/A status: N/A
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i7-8500Y bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    smt: enabled arch: Amber/Kaby Lake note: check rev: 9 cache: L1: 128 KiB
    L2: 512 KiB L3: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1570 high: 1614 min/max: 400/4200 cores: 1: 1608
    2: 1614 3: 1600 4: 1461 bogomips: 12799
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 615 vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915
    v: kernel ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1, DP-2, HDMI-A-1, HDMI-A-2
    bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:591c class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Quanta HP Wide Vision FHD Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-9:3 chip-ID: 0408:5251 class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: i915 display-ID: 0
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: AU Optronics res: 3840x2160 dpi: 333
    size: 293x165mm (11.5x6.5") diag: 336mm (13.2") modes: 3840x2160
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 615 (AML-KBL)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_soc_skl v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:9d71
    class-ID: 0401
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.2.0-39-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 6e:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:24fd class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: wwan0 state: down mac: N/A
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-3:2 chip-ID: 8087:0a2b class-ID: e001
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes
    address: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 119.28 GiB (12.5%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLB1T0HALR-000H1
    size: 953.87 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter>
    rev: EXA73H1Q temp: 29.9 C scheme: MBR
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 936.84 GiB used: 119.27 GiB (12.7%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 512 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 55.0 C pch: 38.5 C mobo: 27.8 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 240 Uptime: 19m wakeups: 6152 Memory: 15.5 GiB
  used: 3.07 GiB (19.8%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A
  Packages: 1785 apt: 1743 snap: 42 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16
  running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.13
```